# How to undo move /home into /old_home?

Tags: partitioning, home-directory

I accidentally skipped the step "Preparing fstab for the switch" and moved on to the next step of "Moving /home into /old_home" under the documentation for setting up a separate home partition here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Is it okay to just do the step "Preparing fstab for the switch" from here or do I have to undo "Moving /home into /old_home"? Is so, how may I do that?

Will editing the fstab file after `cd / && sudo mv /home /old_home && cd / && sudo mkdir -p /home` harm my computer?

Answer (score 3):

If not rebooted yet, it is ok to do it now.

And no, editing `fstab` is safe during and after that command.

Comment: thank you! I went through with the commands and everything seems fine.