# Moving '/home' from a partition to 'real' /home

Tags: home-directory

Having put /home on a separate partition when installing and then added another version of Ubuntu to a third partition and used the /home in common, I see the error of my ways. I want to put both /homes back in their OS trees and repurpose the old common 'home' partition.

I am trying to follow https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving and [How to undo move /home into /old_home?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40337/how-to-undo-move-home-into-old-home)

I know the UUIDs of all partitions and can edit the fstab and #-ed the /home partition. Can't log into the normal GUI as 'cannot update ICEauthority file'. After restarting in recovery mode I see /home has no link to the far home folder.  I can't make a new dir (RO file system) and can't useradd *any* username ('cannot lock /etc/passwd').

My problem is that my only user's home directory is a subdirectory of /home - where I want to move it to, and a link is already in operation with that username!

How do I clean this mess up without yet another reinstall, please?

Comment: It sounds like you know what to do in recovery mode. It's just that you have a RO file system at that point. So first, call `mount -o remount,rw /` in your recovery shell. Then, proceed as you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you can solve issue with [booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub) to single mode.

This way you will get full root privileges and won't get problems with RO file system like in recovery mode. (Another way - boot to recovery and remount partitions with write permissions)

After booting to single mode check files /etc/passwd.lock /etc/gshadow.lock, /etc/shadow.lock. Delete them if exists and try to follow "Home/Moving" manual.

Comment: @timo and apmouse: thank you both for your valuable input - it gave me a few hours of 'learning experience' (I'm a bit slow!) and then I had to accept my limitations and just backed up some files and reinstalled the whole bang-shoot.  Should have just done so in the first place.